# sound design a scene where different radio programs playing at same time

Tags: pro-tools, production, post-production

I am working on a short film and I am stuck in a scene where a busy city is seen from a tall tower...here different radio stations are to be played at the same time with different programs..one playing news ..ads songs etc...I tried by layering different news and making some specific words to be louder of a particular news with other playing at low level...still it's nit creating the chaos ..it's sounding crowded...need advice guys

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to achieve. Exactly what effect are you after?

Comment: Maybe some reverb or echo, possibly with a flanger or phaser?

Answer (score 2):

Pan and EQ each differently. Then mix them all to provide a wash/bed. Then ride the levels so that they take turns "poking" out.